# Angular 4 proxy configuration file not redirecting to the target mentioned instead its redirecting to localhost:4200

Tags: angular

My angular 4 proxy configuration file not redirecting to the target mentioned instead its redirecting to `<http://localhost:4200>`.

Comment: You need to configure your proxy port to angular.Please update your question with the code also

Comment: Angular Proxy config will work only from Angular 6.1 onwards

Comment: Hi suresh i have worked on angular 4 already for the same proxy config but the web service is hosted in localhost:8080 so it worked.But now i am trying to connect splunk so its not happening

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to configure your proxy configuration.

```
{
  "/api": {
     "target":  {
       "host": "localhost",
       "protocol": "http:",
       "port": 8020
     },
     "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

and name this file as proxy.conf.json.

Then as usual run command from your npm console as

> ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

Comment: Thanks bro .i will try this and come back to you

Comment: Just recommend other also this solution by marking answer as useful

Answer (score 0):

you can use http proxy agent

**Package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "https-proxy-agent": "^2.1.0"
}
```

**proxy.config.js**

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "/api/**": {
      target: 'http://localhost:8090',
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
      logLevel: 'debug'
  }
}

function applyProxyAgent() {
  Object.keys(PROXY_CONFIG).forEach(function (key, index) {
      var requiresProxy = true;
      var target = PROXY_CONFIG[key].target;

      if (process.env.NO_PROXY) {
          //check if target is part of no proxy
          process.env.NO_PROXY.split(',').forEach(function (host) {
              if (target.indexOf(host) >= 0 && requiresProxy == true) {
                  requiresProxy = false;
              }
          });

      }
      if (requiresProxy) {
          console.log('Applying proxy agent for ' + target);
          // PROXY_CONFIG[index].agent = process.env.HTTP_PROXY ? new HttpsProxyAgent(process.env.HTTP_PROXY) : undefined;
          PROXY_CONFIG[key].agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(process.env.HTTP_PROXY);
      } else {
          console.log('No proxy agent applied for ' + target);
      }
  });
}
applyProxyAgent();

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```